# Firefox 31.0 Doesn't load some sites after upgrade from 30.0

Tags: firefox, https, certificate

I had Firefox 30.0 and I was able to access some intranet Apache servers using HTTPS just by [bypassing the Untrusted Connection warning](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-untrusted-error-message#w_bypassing-the-warning). After upgrading to Firefox 31.0, in some computers it's not possible to connect to some of our servers anymore. After typing the URL, all we see is a blank page and the "connecting..." message on the status bar.

This happened with some OSX and Windows 7 clients, but for some clients and some servers with the same code, it works fine. Other browsers are also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that works for **OSX** and **Windows 7** and doesn't require the Reset Firefox feature. Basically we want to **Delete or Distrust the "problematic" certificates from the Authorities**:

1. Go to Firefox Menu > Options
2. Go to Advanced tab >Certificates > View Certificates
3. Go to Authorities tab on the Certificate Manager dialog and look for the Certificate Name (*in my case it is an IP number, grouped by the company that issued it*)
4. Select all the "problematic" certificates (*it might have more than one for the same site*) and click on Delete or Distrust and confirm. Here is important to **make  sure no "problematic" certificate is left there**.

Once you followed these steps, close the options dialogs and just access the site with untrusted certificates again and Add Exception to trust the self-signed certificate.

Please refer to these threads for more information:

- [Firefox 31.0 (OSX) Sites with untrusted certificate won't load](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1012728#answer-616338)
- [Security certificate no longer valid after upgrading to latest FF](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1012765#answer-616490)